# Javascript Loop Not Working

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to run a for loop in Javascript and my code does not seem to be working. Any ideas?
My code is as follows right now:

```
var someData = [
 {
   id: 0,
   summary: "Event 1",
   startTime:  new Date(2012,0, 1, 10),
   endTime: new Date(2012,0, 1, 12),
   calendar: "Calendar1"
 },
 {
   id: 1,
   summary: "Event 2",
   startTime:  new Date(2012,0, 1, 14),
   endTime: new Date(2012,0, 1, 15),
   calendar: "Calendar2"
 }
];


var someData = 
    [
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        {
        id:i,
    summary: "Some Event",
    startTime: new Date(2012,8,24,10),
        endTime: new Date(2012,8,24,13),
        calendar: "Calendar"
    },
   }
   ];
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why is it inside array brackets?

Comment: is it running even once? Maybe you have a compile error. Also, I'm not sure if you can run a for loop inside of an array, I'm pretty sure your program is blowing up here. Maybe see if you can find a good JavaScript debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix code into a literal declaration. First create the array, then fill it with data:

```
var someData = [];

for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
  someData.push(
    {
      id:i,
      summary: "Some Event",
      startTime: new Date(2012,8,24,10),
      endTime: new Date(2012,8,24,13),
      calendar: "Calendar"
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot write for..loop like that.. Try below,

```
var someData = [];

for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
   someData.push({
        id:i,
        summary: "Some Event",
        startTime: new Date(2012,8,24,10),
        endTime: new Date(2012,8,24,13),
        calendar: "Calendar"
    });
}
```

Comment: I usually write in java and am fairly new to js

Comment: @Mac10 Sure no problem.. You can start reading all the basics at [MDN javascript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript)

Comment: @Mac10 I have never seen a for loop nested in an array declaration in Java. I don't think it's valid there either.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `push()`. You can't put bodies of code inside an array unless it's an anonymous function contained in an object.

```
var someData = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    someData.push({
        id: i,
        summary: "Some Event",
        startTime: new Date(2012, 8, 24, 10),
        endTime: new Date(2012, 8, 24, 13),
        calendar: "Calendar"
    });
}
```